# update state with another state in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have a state which needs to be updated everytime when another state changes.So I used used effect with dependencty array item of another state but it is causing infinit render.
I want to use these variables as states.
I want totalAmount to be a state variable for which other varables are needed to be state(discount subtotal etc.).
What could be the solution to this.

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

function App() {
  let order = [
    {
      qty: 2,
      name: 'Margarita A',
      variant: 'crab & cucumber',
      price: '412.00',
    }
  ];


  let [discount, setDiscount] = useState(759.5),
    [deliveryFee, setDeliveryFee] = useState(12.0),
    [taxes, setTaxes] = useState(46.15),
    [subtotal, setSubtotal] = useState(0),
    [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTotalAmount(subtotal - discount + deliveryFee + taxes);
  }, [subtotal, discount, deliveryFee, taxes]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container">    
          <div className="orderItems">
            {order.map((item, i) => {
              // subtotal += +item.price;
              setSubtotal((prev) => prev + +item.price);

              return (
                <div className="orderItem" key={i}>
                  <span className="orderItemPrice">₹{item.price}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="summary">
          <span className="summaryTitle">Summary</span>
          <div className="total amountBox">
            <span>Total</span>
            <span>₹ {totalAmount}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="placeOrder">
        <button onClick={(e, totalAmount) => {}}>PLACE ORDER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do not change state in render method, setSubtotal() should not be called in render, else it will run infinitely since on state change the component will rerender

Comment: If you want to persist subtotal value through out render use ref here, and set value subtotal.current = 0 every time the order array changes (currently order array will not change on each render, since you are not setting it though API)

Comment: even If i am update subtotal using setSubtotal() inside App not in return then also, it is going in infinite render. what's wrong ther @AbdulMalik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The Problem

the problem is not with your `useEffect` hook, it's working properly and called once at component did mount. the problem is with the `setSubtotal((prev) => prev + +item.price);` in your `return` method.

Every change on state variables will cause re-rendering, with every re-render your `order.map` will be recreated. so changing the state during `order.map` will cause re-render and the re-render cause the `order.map` to draw again. It's the cause of your infinity re-render.

**Note:** you can simply comment the `setState` inside of your `map` function to stop this behavior.

##### The Solution

There are some options to control this situation like using `useRef` for `subtotal` to prevent the cause of re-rendering.

Also, you can calculate your `subtotal` inside of your `useEffect` hook before calculation of `totalAmount` and setting it.

```
function App() {
  let order = [
    {
      qty: 2,
      name: "Margarita A",
      variant: "crab & cucumber",
      price: "412.00"
    }
  ];

  const [discount, setDiscount] = useState(59.5);
  const [deliveryFee, setDeliveryFee] = useState(12.0);
  const [taxes, setTaxes] = useState(46.15);
  const [subtotal, setSubtotal] = useState(0);
  const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localSubtotal = order.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => (acc += Number(curr.price)),
      0
    );

    setSubtotal(localSubtotal);
    setTotalAmount(localSubtotal - discount + deliveryFee + taxes);
  }, [discount, deliveryFee, taxes, order]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="orderItems">
          {order.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <div className="orderItem" key={i}>
                <span className="orderItemPrice">₹{item.price}</span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div className="summary">
          <div>
            <span>Sub Total: {subtotal}</span>
          </div>
          <span className="summaryTitle">Summary</span>
          <div className="total amountBox">
            <span>Total</span>
            <span>₹ {totalAmount}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="placeOrder">
        <button onClick={(e, totalAmount) => {}}>PLACE ORDER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note:** don't forget to pass the `order` array in the array of dependency in `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Thank You nima, your answer was helpful and I got to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: as a side note, since the first comment is outdated, it's better to remove by the `delete` button.  @Anand